# Extracting/subsetting data in R based on separate datasets

Tags: r, merge

I have two separate (large) datasets, and I need to isolate the observations from one, based on presence/absence in the other dataset. Specifically, I have a dataset of phenology, where each month trees are observed for fruiting patterns, etc. I have another dataset with feeding observations of mammalian frugivores. What I want to do is to extract (isolate? index?) the months of phenological data when there were observed feeding observations. Phenology was taken every month, but feeding observations were not. I know there must be a simple, straightforward way to do this in R but I have not figured it out. I included some sample data, as well as the code I tried (and failed) to use. Also, could someone explain why when I use the "merge" function it returns more than double the original amount of observations? Thank you in advance!

```
> p<-read.csv("PhenoSample.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
> 
> str(p)
'data.frame':   29 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Tree.ID: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ yr.mo  : num  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ Status : Factor w/ 3 levels "f","i","r": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 ...
> p
   Tree.ID   yr.mo Status
1        1 2007.07      r
2        2 2007.07      r
3        3 2007.07      r
4        4 2007.07      r
5        5 2007.07      r
6        6 2007.07      r
7        7 2007.08      r
8        8 2007.08      r
9        9 2007.08      r
10      10 2007.08      i
11      11 2007.08      i
12      12 2007.09      i
13      13 2007.09      i
14      14 2007.09      i
15      15 2007.09      i
16      16 2007.09      i
17      17 2007.09      i
18      18 2007.09      i
19      19 2007.10      i
20      20 2007.10      f
21      21 2007.10      f
22      22 2007.10      f
23      23 2007.10      f
24      24 2007.10      f
25      25 2007.10      f
26      26 2007.10      f
27      27 2007.10      f
28      28 2007.10      f
29      29 2007.10      f
> 
> f <- read.csv("FeedObsSample.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
> 
> str(f)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Tree.ID: int  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 19 ...
 $ yr.mo  : num  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ Animal : Factor w/ 3 levels "GN","KL","KL ": 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
> f
   Tree.ID   yr.mo Animal
1        3 2007.07     KL
2        4 2007.07    KL 
3        5 2007.07     GN
4        6 2007.07     GN
5        7 2007.08     GN
6        8 2007.08     GN
7        9 2007.08     KL
8       10 2007.08     KL
9       11 2007.08     KL
10      19 2007.10     KL
11      20 2007.10     KL
12      21 2007.10     KL
13      22 2007.10     GN
14      23 2007.10     GN
15      24 2007.10     GN
16      25 2007.10     GN
17      26 2007.10     GN
> 
> newdata <- p[match(p$yr.mo== f$yr.mo)] 
Error in match(p$yr.mo == f$yr.mo) : 
  argument "table" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In p$yr.mo == f$yr.mo :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 
> newdata<- merge(p, f, by = c("yr.mo"))
> 
> str(newdata)
'data.frame':   137 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ yr.mo    : num  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ Tree.ID.x: int  3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
```

Comment: edit your question with a representative sample of both your data.frames using `dput`

Comment: Do you want `subset(p, yr.mo %in% unique(f$yr.mo))` ?

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I needed. I knew it was something simple. Thank you!! @jogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
subset(p, yr.mo %in% unique(f$yr.mo))
```